# Old SWF files won't play after updating Flash Player

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Many thanks to anyone who can help me out of a frustrating pickle...

My SWF files don't work anymore.  I have about 160 Recordings of online webinar-type classes, created by a third party web conference provider, and they are all in SWF format.  They used to play fine (using Mac & Safari) with an older version of Flash Player, but they stopped working several months ago, after I updated Flash Player.  I don't understand very well how Flash works, but each SWF file is contained in a folder with many other SWF, FLV, and XML files, and I think the problem is that the master SWF file can no longer link properly to these subsidiary resources.  When I try to play the master SWF file, the windows and controls for the webinar appear, but each window just displays an endlessly looping progress bar or progress wheel, as if it is looking for something to put in the window and can't find it.  I tried opening the primary SWF file with Flash Professional, just to see if I could figure out how to edit or fix the file, and the "Output" tab of Flash told me this:

> "TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference."

That's as far as I can go.  I tried reverting to an earlier version of Flash, but my computer wouldn't let me, claiming that that would pose a security risk.

Does anyone know how I can view my recordings again, or even better, convert them to MP4?  (I've tried downloading numerous SWF converter programs, but they all have the same basic problem--they don't recognize the content.)  I don't even care about interactivity.  All I want is just a viewable video file.

Thanks.

Comment: You say in the folders you have some flv files. Those are video files (flash format) so they might contain all your recordings.

Comment: You could try downloading an older version of Flash from this page http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html You should use the standalone projector to open the files.